# Read lParam sent from c++ to C# as string

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

I have a c++ application which uses `SendNotifyMessage` to redirect a *CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT* to C# code. Now, I want to change it to *WM_COPYDATA* but I can't make it work.

C++ code:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgHookCallback(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam){
if (code >= 0)
{
    UINT msg = 0;
    UINT msg2 = 0;

    msg = RegisterWindowMessage("WILSON_HOOK_GETMSG");
    msg2 = RegisterWindowMessage("WILSON_HOOK_GETMSG_PARAMS");

    HWND dstWnd = (HWND)GetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HWND_GETMSG");

    MSG* pMsg = (MSG*)lparam;

    if (msg != 0 && pMsg->message != msg && pMsg->message != msg2)
    {
        if (pMsg->message == CB_ADDSTRING)
        {
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg, (WPARAM)pMsg->hwnd, pMsg->message);
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg2, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam); //plus more code...
```

Now, as my intention is to read the string in `pMsg->lParam` and I can't make it work from the c# side*, I'm trying to use WM_COPYDATA this way:

```
                SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg, (WPARAM)pMsg->hwnd, pMsg->message);
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg2, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam);

            // Added code
            CString *message = (CString*)pMsg->lParam;
            COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;
            cpd.dwData = 0;
            cpd.cbData = message->GetLength();
            cpd.lpData = (void*)message->GetBuffer(cpd.cbData);
            ::SendMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)pMsg->hwnd, (LPARAM)&cpd);
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)pMsg->hwnd, (LPARAM)&cpd);
```

However, I never receive any *WM_COPYDATA* in my c# application*.

Here is the C# part:

```
        int CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT = 0x0158;
    public const Int32 WM_COPYDATA = 0x4A;
    private void test(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        if (Message.ToInt32() == CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT)
        {
            String one = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(lParam); // This gives accessviolationexception
            String dos = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lParam);   // returns empty string
            Console.WriteLine("SOMETHING RECEIVED: "+one+". dos: "+dos+". tres: "+lParam.ToString()); // last part is only an intptr
        }
        if (Message.ToInt32() == WM_COPYDATA) // never true
            Console.WriteLine("COPYDATA: ");
    }
```

I've tried many solutions I've read but none seems to work. How do I read the lParam (which is a String really) from c++ in my c# function? I want to get the string.

EDIT1:

I've tried couple of ways to get WM_COPYDATA working but didn't succeed. Here they are:

```
                    // Test 1: c# never receives anything
                COPYDATASTRUCT* copy_data = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)(pCwpStruct->lParam);
                SendMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)pCwpStruct->hwnd, (LPARAM)&copy_data);
                SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)pCwpStruct->hwnd, (LPARAM)&copy_data);

                // Test 2: c# never receives anything
                LPCTSTR lpszString = (LPCTSTR)pCwpStruct->lParam;
                COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
                cds.dwData = 0;
                cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR)* (_tcslen(lpszString) + 1);
                cds.lpData = (PVOID)lpszString;
                SendMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)pCwpStruct->hwnd, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);
                SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)pCwpStruct->hwnd, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a comment with many corrections but it has dissapeared, don't know why. I followed some suggestions and I solved it. Here's the final code:

C++:

```
                LPCTSTR lpszString = (LPCTSTR)pCwpStruct->lParam;
                COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
                cds.dwData = 0;
                cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR)* (_tcslen(lpszString) + 1);
                cds.lpData = (PVOID)lpszString;
                SendMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)pCwpStruct->hwnd, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);
```

Note that I changed *SendNotifyMessage* to *SendMessage*. It's the only way I could make it work.

In the c# application:

```
public override void ProcessWindowMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
        {

            if (m.Msg == WM_COPYDATA)
            {
                COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
                cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));

                if (cds.cbData > 0)
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[cds.cbData];
                    Marshal.Copy(cds.lpData, data, 0, cds.cbData);
                    System.Text.Encoding unicodeStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                    char[] myString = unicodeStr.GetChars(data);
                    string returnText = new string(myString);   // Here is the info
                }
                ...
```

Comment: The reason it works with SendMessage and does not work with SendNotifyMessage is that SendNotifyMessage is asynchronous.  This means that your function that is making the call likely exits before the receiver gets the message.  Since windows messages contain pointers the pointer to the data you are trying to send is gone by the time the receiver gets the message.  When you use SendMessage your sending code blocks until the receiver gets and consumes the message.  Thus the data in your sending function still exists when the receiver gets the message.